# PayPal transaction using Mobile Payment Library

Tags: android, ios, ios6, paypal

I come to know that using PayPal SDK for iOS and Android only app owner can be the receiver of the money. I can't transfer money to some other person.

Now, I want to use MPL for this but have few doubts.

- Does MPL allow to send money to anyone?
- Does MPL support all currencies or is there any way to handle the case where local currency is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPL allows to send money to anyone. But it does not support all currencies and countries. I tested the sample app its library provides and when currency-country was not supported it did not give any error but money was not transferred to receiver in sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

@Akash, this is Dave from PayPal.

The MPL documentation can be found here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/

and the MPL for Android reference manual is here:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_android.pdf

I do not work directly with MPL, but my understanding is that it will indeed allow you to send money to any recipient you specify, and that it will handle any of the currencies that PayPal normally supports.

Comment: I downloaded MPL library and played with sample project provided in it. I have 2 doubts. First one, 2nd of your links is document where I found list of supported currencies. There it states that "NOTE:This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only." Does this mean that I can use CAD only if my account is created in Canada? Second doubt, If I use currency other than USD then it returns SUCCESSFUL, but actually money is not added to receiver's account. I am testing in sandbox.

Comment: @Akash, the notes on page 39 of that document that indicate support only for in-country accounts appear to apply only to the Brazilian Real and the Malaysian Ringgit. The other listed currencies, including CAD, do not have that note attached to them. Regarding your second doubt, I don't know enough about MPL and Sandbox accounts to be able to advise you. You might want to start a new question about that specific issue, and/or contact [PayPal Developer Technical Support](https://www.paypal.com/dts/).